# How to send a message with "\0" to a Server via TCP

Tags: c++, tcp, null, client

I've managed to create a connection between my Program(client) and a Server.
Now I want to send the following Text `"TOR\0"`. The Server explicit needs this Info for starting an Operation.
The problem is, that everytime I try to define the text

```
char a[]="TOR\0";
```

My client only sends three bytes... Without the NULL at the end.

I can send 5 different Characters like `{"T","O","R","\","0"}`, but I know I need 4 Bytes of Data. I also know the four Bytes need to have  the information "T", "O", "R", "\0". But everytime I try sending this my cpp only sends "T", "O", "R", because it stops reading at the `NULL` which represents the end of line.

I also tried fixing the length in the send-function. I know I have to specify the length by sending it. But by fixing the length on 4 doesn't work. I use this to see if it worked:

```
Result = send( ConnectSocket, a, (int)strlen(a), 0 );
cout << Result << endl;
```

How do I attache the NULL at the end of the text without causing it C++ to stop reading the message at that exact point?

Comment: What do you mean by "fixing the length on 4 doesn't work"?

Comment: `strlen(a)` -> `strlen(a) + 1`.

Comment: `(int)strlen(a)` I would guess this also is 3, not the 4 bytes you want to send.

Comment: exactly that. I could simply write an 4 or an strlen(a)+1

Comment: (int)strlen(a) is 3 in "TOR\0"

Comment: Do you realize that `"\0"` is an escape sequence? `"TOR\0"` string literal contains `{'T', 'O', 'R', 0, 0}` - two terminating nulls.

Comment: If you are sending embedded nulls you have no business using `strlen()` at all. On the other hand you shouldn't have to send an embedded null in the first place. Is that really the application protocol?

Comment: I tried sending just "TOR", but that won't work either...

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "won't work"? `"TOR"` contains 4 bytes and ends with a null-terminator. `strlen` does not count null terminators so it will return 3.

Comment: I know it is an escape sequence, but how do I send it? It seems that Cpp uses the escape sequence by not reading the message any further. I could write `"abc\0de"`, but the output is only `"abc"`

Comment: It only contains 3 bytes... that`s my problem. It should contain 4

Comment: If you specify length as 4 bytes then 4 bytes will be sent. If you try to write it into `cout` it will only write till terminating null.

Comment: So you mean it sends 4 bytes, but with `cout` it just prints 3 and the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: Most of C and C++ text io functions only print string till terminating null. So yes, `cout` will only print `TOR` out of `"TOR\0";` or `"TOR";` and `abc` out of `"abc\0de"`.

Comment: What exactly does 'causing it C++ to stop reading the message at that exact point' mean? The only thing stopping at that point in the code you posted is `strlen()`, which is C, not C++.

Answer (score 0):

String `"TOR\0"` has 5 characters for you, however C++ - in the same way as C - understands every sequence of `\<character>` as a single special character. So `\0` is one single character NULL (code 0).

This notation is superfluous, as every string in C/C++ written as "string" has terminating NULL. For example `"abc"` is equivalent of `{'a','b','c','\0'}`. So `"TOR\0"` means `{'T','O','R','\0','\0'}`.

The `strlen` function returns the length of string defined as a number of characters from beginning of the string before NULL terminator. So, `strlen("TOR\0") == 3` because there are three characters before NULL.

If you intention is to send literal characters as you wrote them: 'T', 'O', 'R', backslash and '0', you can do that in one of those ways:

```
char a[]={'T','O','R','\\','0','\0'};
char a[]="TOR\\0";
```

Please mind the `\\` which is interpreted by C/C++ as single backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `sizeof a` instead of `strlen(a)` if you're dealing in embedded nulls.

Comment: Now *what* contains 8 bytes? What are you talking about? `sizeof a` is four.

Comment: Yes, but it is extremely dangerous to use sizeof here. sizeof will return the size of the array if passed an array, but the size of the pointer (so, probably 4 or 8 bytes) if passed a pointer. In pratice, they are nearly the same thing, just passing the array a to another function or declaring it as char *a rather than char a[] will return 4 or 8 and fail silently.

Comment: @Paul-LouisAgeneau There is no pointer here. It is far from clear what the OP is actually talking about. Let's not complicate it further.

Comment: @EJP Yes, you are right of course, and sizeof works here. I was just pointing to OP that the use of sizeof can be really tricky in that particular case, which might explain why he gets 8 bytes.

Comment: @Paul-LouisAgeneau Could be, who knows? Until he explains himself and posts some complete code, including the receiving code, it's anybody's guess. I've never even seen an application protocol where you had to transmit a trailing null, for example.